# class inside a class c#

Tags: c#

I want to define a class inside a class.

example:

```
private class newClient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }        

    private class ClientExtraData
    {
       public string ExtraField1 { get; set; }
       public string ExtraField2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now i want to access the ExtraField1 in such way:

```
newClient nclnt= new newClient();
string s=nclnt.ClientExtraData.ExtraField1;
```

Can this be done?

Comment: What is your original task you're solving in this strange way?

Comment: Make it static or create an instance in the parent class.

Comment: How about declaring a public property returning `ClientExtraData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't access the internal class in this way `nclnt.ClientExtraData.ExtraField1;` because you must have an instance of that object if you want to access its properties.
Then you can't use the `private` access modifier but you have to use `internal` in this way:

```
class newClient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ClientExtraData clientExtraData{ get; set; }

    public newClient()
    {
        clientExtraData = new ClientExtraData();
    }

    internal class ClientExtraData
    {
        public string ExtraField1 { get; set; }
        public string ExtraField2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Or you can make `ClientExtraData` `public` instead of `internal` if you want to make it accessible outside `newClient` in this way:

```
newClient.ClientExtraData clientExtraData = new newClient.ClientExtraData();
```

---

So then you can do:

```
newClient nclnt= new newClient();
string s = nclnt.clientExtraData.ExtraField1;
```

Answer (score 3):

To Achieve the below,

```
newClient nclnt= new newClient();
string s=nclnt.ClientExtraData.ExtraField1;
```

All you need to do is expose a property like this

```
private class NewClient
{
        public class NewClient() 
        {
            this.ClientExtraData = new ClientData();
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public ClientData ClientExtraData {get;set;}
}
```

where `ClientData` is a class in your assembly.

Comment: Don't forget to instantiate it in the constructor(s).

Comment: @Aphelion I would leave that to the developer implementing it as, few scenarios would require to Initialize it when creating the class.

Comment: I don't agree. He wants to access the field, so it should be there ;)

Comment: @Aphelion -  Yeah it makes sense. Updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

No it can't be done like that. The class is not a method, property or anything which is instanziated by the class.

It is also very bad design :-)

You could however say:

var myclass = new ClassOne.ClassTwo()

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this kind of stuff like this:

```
//the two classes can live in the same code file, if you want.
private class ClientExtraDataClass
{
    public string ExtraField1 { get; set; }
   public string ExtraField2 { get; set; }
}
private class newClient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    //you may want to make it a readonly property too, 
    // it depends on your needs.
    public ClientExtraDataClass ClientExtraData = new ClientExtraDataClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to archieve exactly this with your code

```
newClient nclnt= new newClient();
string s=nclnt.ClientExtraData.ExtraField1;
```

the `newClient` class have to be `public`
and the `ClientExtraData` class have to be `public` and `static`

but the better approach is definetly to create to classes, where newClient contains a Get-Property to an instance of the ClientExtraData class.

look at [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the inner class public so that it can be accessed.
2. Make the property you need to access as static (or create instance to access the field)

class newClient
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

```
    public class ClientExtraData
    {
        public static string ExtraField1 { get { return "10"; }  }
        public string ExtraField2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Access code:

newClient nclnt = new newClient();
string s = newClient.ClientExtraData.ExtraField1;